# EKEvent marked private for Exchange event on iOS

Tags: ios, exchange-server, eventkit, ekevent

I'm currently working on a project where I need to access whether an event is marked as private or not. This is a feature most commonly seen in Exchange calendars.

The functionality is available in the native iOS Calendar app, but also in third party calendar apps like Fantastical, which leads me to believe it's not necessarily private API.

Here's a picture of an event marked as private in Fantastical:

[image: Fantastical handling private property]

However, when looking at EKEvent I see nothing that would indicate that the event is private.

Here is a print of the EKEvent:

```
EKEvent <0x13fcb80c0>
{
     EKEvent <0x13fcb80c0>
{    title =        So private; 
     location =     ; 
     calendar =     EKCalendar <0x13fef4110> {title = Calendar; type = Exchange; allowsModify = YES; color = #FF9500;}; 
     alarms =       (null); 
     URL =          (null); 
     lastModified = 2016-02-16 12:14:24 +0000; 
     startTimeZone =    Europe/Berlin (GMT+1) offset 3600; 
     startTimeZone =    Europe/Berlin (GMT+1) offset 3600 
}; 
     location =     ; 
     structuredLocation =   (null); 
     startDate =    2016-02-16 12:00:00 +0000; 
     endDate =      2016-02-16 14:00:00 +0000; 
     allDay =       0; 
     floating =     0; 
     recurrence =   (null); 
     attendees =    (null); 
     travelTime =   (null); 
     startLocation =    (null);
};
```

When printing the notes property found on EKCalendarItem I get: `(NSTaggedPointerString *) $34 = 0xa00000000000a0d2 @"\r\n"`, which again does not seem like an obvious reveal of a private setting.

What am I missing? How can Fantastical get the private property of an event?

Comment: Presumably the Fantastical screenshot is a CalDAV calendar? Does it also show the private switch on an Exchange calendar? Fantastical doesn't seem to use EventKit for CalDAV servers, right from their front page: "Fantastical now has its own CalDAV engine".